# Php file gets downloaded instead of executing on OSX with Nginx server

Tags: php, macos, nginx, osx-elcapitan

Hi I have followed https://www.sylvaindurand.org/setting-up-a-nginx-web-server-on-macos/ to install nginx and php.
I am using OSX El-capitan, php-fpm and nginx versions are nginx 1.12.1 and php7
My server is working as I am able to open html file stored at document root in browser but when I try to open php file stored at same location it gets downloaded instead of executing

My nginx.conf file content are as below:

```
#user  username staff;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
#log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
#charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   /Users/username/Sites;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        }


        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /Users/username/Sites;
        }
# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
#
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           /Users/username/Sites;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
           include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
    #}
    include servers/*;
}
```

Comment: Show us your config files for nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
root           html;
must be changed with path to your web, 
root   /Users/username/Sites;
```

replace with this in your location php section:

```
 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Comment: Check if php-fpm run on corect port: netstat -tnlp | grep php-fpm. Did you restart nginx after editing?

Comment: and php file is not getting downloaded now but I am getting file not found issue for php files

Comment: Yes I restarted nginx with command: 'sudo nginx -s reload'  and php-fpm runs on port 9000

Comment: index.php is in /Users/username/Site folder and nginx have rights to execute? try to comment include servers/*; line.

Comment: yes its in /Users/username/Site folder and nginx have rights to use it

Comment: replace with this in your location php section: fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

Comment: Hey thanks its working :) thank u so much edit your answer and add above step so that I can approve your answer

Comment: Great, You're Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved Issue with bellow lines in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            include        fastcgi.conf; # Added this line
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name; #Commented this line
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; #Added this line
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
```